# reading all spans of a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div inside which i have number of spans. Now i want to read all text of all spans along with thrir id and populate it into a javascript map  where key = spanid and value =" text of span.How can i do it?

```
Eg <div mydiv="xyx" >   
     <span id ="sp1" > M/span>
     <span id ="sp2" > M/span>
     .... 
      ..

   </div>
```

How can i populate the map?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the elements using `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByTagName`, then iterate through them and add them to the object. Use [`textContent` and `innerText`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04) to obtain the text of the `span` element, and insert them into the object like so:

```
var spans = document.getElementById('xyx').getElementsByTagName('span'), 
    obj = {};

for(var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++){
    obj[spans[i].id] = spans[i].textContent || spans[i].innerText;
}
```

See it working here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/SJs4h/

Answer (score 3):

```
var container=document.getElementById('xyx');
var spanArray=container.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var s=0;s<spanArray.length;s++){
  spanText=spanArray[s].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery its very simple:

```
var spans = $('#xyx').find('span');
var arr = new Array();
 foreach(spans as span)
 {
       arr[$(span).attr('id')] = $(span).text;
 }
```

Hope i helped.

**Update:**
None jquery way:

```
var spans = document.getElementById('xyx');
spans = spans.getElementsByTagName('span');
var arr = new Array();
foreach(spans as span) 
{
   arr[span.getAttribute('id')] = arr[span.innerHTML];
}
```

Comment: @WEBProject Well, there are several problems with this code - it would've been perfect in PHP, but JavaScript does not have associative arrays, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a ECMAScript 5 feature and does not work like that, and `new Array` is a lot more verbose than simply `[]`